# Select from table depending on entries in other table

Tags: mysql

This is the setup:

Table A has a connection to table B. There are multiple entries (0 to n) in table B that can have a matching record in table A.

How do I form a query that gives me a record from table A only if a certain amount of matching records exist in table B?

Example:

Table A has clothing in it. Table B has attributes for clothing.

Table B has a foreign key to table A so it would look something like this:

```
id  fid_clothing1  attributeA
id  fid_clothing1  attributeB
id  fid_clothing1  attributeC
id  fid_clothing2  attributeA
id  fid_clothing2  attributeB
```

Now, I want only the clothes which have attribute `attributeA` AND `attributeB` AND `attributeC`. This is not a problem if I do a OR-query but I can't just do something like:

```
SELECT * from tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB on tableB.fid_cloting = tableA.id
WHERE attribute='A' AND attribute='B' AND attribute='C'
```

This condition will never evaluate to true. How do I do that?

Comment: You Should Use With clouse I Think So

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with 3 inner joins... i.e. give me table A rows that have the attributes I want

```
SELECT A.id FROM tableA A
INNER JOIN tableB BA ON A.id = BA.fid_clothing AND BA.Attribute='A'
INNER JOIN tableB BB ON A.id = BB.fid_clothing AND BB.Attribute='B'
INNER JOIN tableB BC ON A.id = BC.fid_clothing AND BC.Attribute='C'
GROUP BY A.id
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it generalises poorly (what if your item of clothing had 99 attributes)?

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/04/group_concat-useful-group-by-extension/) to fetch a single row of all attributes for a given piece of clothing:

```
SELECT id,GROUP_CONCAT(attribute order by attribute) as Attributes 
FROM tableB 
GROUP BY id;
```

Giving something like:

```
| id | Attributes |
|  1 | A,B,C      |
```

From this resultset, you could select those ids for which the concatenated attribute matched the set of attributes you were looking for.

select id from MyConcatenatedResults where Attributes = 'A,B,C'

Comment: Kind of goes against normalisation principles but looks like it should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

May be this one.. have to try it

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEA a, TABLE b 
WHERE a.id = b.clothing_id 
AND a.id in (SELECT clothing_id from TABLEB where attribute = 'A' AND clothing_id = a.id
UNION select clothing_id from TABLEB where attribute = 'B' AND clothing_id = a.id
UNION select clothing_id from TABLEB where attribute = 'C' AND clothing_id = a.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is as follows, which requires zero joins, but a nested sub-query... have tries this on a dummy database, and it seems to do the job. Hope it helps.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA A 
WHERE id IN ( 
              SELECT clothing_id
              FROM tableB B
              WHERE
                attribute =  "A"
                OR attribute =  "B"
                OR attribute =  "C"
              GROUP BY clothing_id
              HAVING count(*) = 3
            )
```

Comment: You'd want to add a unique key on clothing_id, attribute just incase a shirt had two sleves